# socket.io: Avoiding server to client to sever communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

This may seem odd but I have a situation where I'm keeping an array of uses in `io.on('connection', function(socket) { ... });` scope for each user currently connected to a room. So when a user disconnects, I need to update that array on the server. The issue is, since this array is unique to each socket/user I can't just update the array directly.

So what I'm doing is broadcasting an update to all users then immediately having users emit a message back. Is there a cleaner method of doing this?

Quick and dirty example:

```
// server.js
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var usersArray = getUsersArray();
    socket.on('user array update', function() {
        usersArray = removeUser(user);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('user disconnected', user);
    });

});

//client.js
socket.on('user disconnect', function(user) {
    socket.emit('user array update', user);
});
```

I'm new to node.js but this ping pong type communication feels a bit unnecessary, is this pretty standard or is there a better way I should be doing this?

Comment: Can you just define your array at a higher scope so all your user's message handling can share access to the same array?

Comment: I could, I was trying to avoid it since each room has unique users in it so while I could have nested arrays of users in rooms, I'd really worry about scaling, I feel there are potential scaling concerns with this? However I suppose it might be bette than what I'm currently doing.

Comment: What's in these arrays?  socket.io already keeps a list of every socket in a room.  You don't have to keep that.

Comment: Right now it consists of a username (that they enter when they visit the site) and a 16 char randomly generated ID. That way I can have a second array that I compare against the user array of users who have indicated that they are "ready to begin" (like a button). I need to wait for all users to be ready before I begin.